# How do I force a process to stay on even after logging out or move process out of user-space memory?

Tags: windows-8, memory, user-accounts, process

I am quite often uploading various big files to various websites with my web browser on a slow connection and not every website support resuming of the upload.

Now my lsass.exe process consumes around 1GB of memory and there is absolutely no known (to me) way to see what causes this memory usage, so I want to log out and in to fix the problem.

However I'm uploading a file which is 6 gb, and it's currently on 20% in 3 hours time. How can I ensure my browser stays open, even after I log off and log in to windows?

I did try to see if this memory usage is caused by any other accounts on the PC but there are no accounts with passwords and guest account is disabled.. and this is the `net users` output:

```
C:\windows\system32>net user

User accounts for \\GAMER

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator            Guest                    User
The command completed successfully.


C:\windows\system32>
```

Comment: You can't. If you want to find out what's using your memory, use [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx).

Comment: It seems like your *actual problem* is that lsass.exe eats 1GB of memory, but what you are asking for help with is *leaving your browser running when you log off*. Two different problems. Technically you could run the browser with `srvany` as a service account (with desktop access) and RDP into the service account or so, but this is a huge hack and probably won't work that well, esp. related to hardware acceleration, etc. You should just figure out why `lsass.exe` eats a gig of RAM. I am leaning toward virus since this never happens under normal circumstances if lsass is not corrupted.

Comment: Hm I fired up that progrm and go to lsass.exe and it just shows the 1 gb there, how do I find out exactly what uses what? And I doubt it's a virus - it's a 2 weeks old laptop and the only thing I did install with administrator rights were the drivers from the official page

Comment: which (standalone)freeware antivirus can scan for such viruses?

Comment: I scanned LSASS.exe (35.840 bytes / 36.864 on disk) from system32 dir (rmb process -> open file location) on virustotal.com and it's clean..

Comment: sorry, with standalone I mean portable.

Comment: hm, maybe it's my Gigabit Ethernet LAN driver? I just restarted the pc, played a few games, fired up/closed a few programs, did my usual things, music, streaming etc.. nothing. 3 mb. soon I will get my old dusty laptop with a gigabit card in it from the safe and connect these two PC's and I'll monitor the ram usage on large / many file transfers